# homotopy inverse of the cap product

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

The cap product with the fundamental cycle of an oriented, triangulated $n$-manifold $X$ defines a chain map $-\cap X: C^*(X,A) \to C_{n-*}(X,A)$, where $A$ is any abelian coefficient group.

It's easy to see by computing examples that this map is neither surjective nor injective in general. However, it induces isomorphisms $H^*(X,A) \simeq H_{*-n}(X,A)$ so it is a quasi-isomorphism.

Hence my question: is there any well-known or simple construction of an "inverse map"
$$f:C_*(X,A) \to C^{*-n}(X,A)$$
such that $f(-) \cap X$ and $f(- \cap X)$ are homotopic to the identity maps on $C_*$ and $C^*$, respectively?

Comment: You need $X$ compact (or to take Borel-Moore homology, or compactly supported cohomology) if you want such an isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks, although the maps are (locally) indistinguishable in all those cases, they just induce isomorphisms on different versions of the cohomology of the complex.